# Control key broken in Firefox 108 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, firefox

I use ctl+ to zoom text often. Just in the last two days this stopped working. Pressing control seems to send off multiple ctl - signals and it makes the web page so small I can't read it. I removed and re installed -- no luck. I installed with apt install, not snap.

I switched out the keyboard, so its not that. I created a second user on my machine, and the problem is the same on the second user. I was hoping there was some user specific setting that got messed up, but I guess that's not it either.

Comment: There is no problem here (FF 108, Ubuntu 22.10). I suggest you use the `xev` command to test your Ctrl key.

Comment: xev shows the control keys are fine.  Firefox has been fine until a few days ago.  I'm wondering if some config info exists somewhere that is bad?

Comment: Can you still zoom with Ctrl and the numeric keypad `+` and `-` keys?

Comment: No, as soon as I depress ctl the screen zooms out rapidly -- as if I typed ctl - repeatedly

Comment: I should be clear this key only seems broken on Firefox.  Chrome works fine, its just that I prefer firefox